# constraint validation on @RequestParam does not seems to be working

Tags: spring, rest, validation

I have a `GetAll` operation that pull all employees in a `deptNo`. I want to add a constraint that checks the size on `deptNumber` on my `RequestParameter` but it doesn't seems to be validating the parameter.
How can I achieve the validation?

```
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<EmpSummary>> getEmps(
@Valid @RequestParam @Max(1) @Max(999) Optional<Long> deptNUmber)
```

---

```
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OntApiController implements OntApi {
    private final OntService service;
    private NativeWebRequest    nativeWebRequest;
    private HttpServletRequest  httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<OntSummaryResource>> getOnts(
            @Valid @RequestParam @Min(1L) @Max(999L) Optional<Long> ontNumber,
            @Valid @RequestParam @Min(1) @Max(999) Optional<Integer> model,
            ...... more parameters);
```

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: **No validator could be found for constraint
>   'javax.validation.constraints.Max**' validating type
>   'java.util.Optional'. Check configuration for

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method) : You should add annotation `@Validated` to your controller, if you're using method argument validation.

Now your code would be like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/your_api")
@Validated
public class YourController {

   @GetMapping("/your_endpoint")
   public ResponseEntity> getEmps(
     @RequestParam @Min(1) @Max(999) Optional deptNUmber){
```

Comment: I have tried @Validated, but it doesn't seem to be working. Let me put in more details in my main question

Comment: While this basically works, the resulting `ConstraintViolationException` leads to an internal server error (500). So you need an exception handler to turn this into a "bad request" instead. It's just weird that Spring (Boot) doesn't handle this out of the box.